# Action Script 3, Grid and GridRow in Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to create one Table in Flex which contains sub sections,colspans and rowsans. 
 I  already build this with <mx:Grid> and <mx:GridRow> like hardcoded in flex, but I want to build this dynamically with Action Script. 
I really not sure how to build it.
This is my sample code need to convert to Action Script

```
<mx:Grid id="metricsGrid" styleName="grid" backgroundColor="blue" horizontalAlign="center" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:GridRow id="cashMetricsGridHeaderRow" >
        <mx:GridItem colSpan="3" styleName="gridItem" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" >
            <mx:Label text="{ getTodaysDateWithTitle() }" styleName="boldFontWeight"></mx:Label>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>

    <mx:GridRow id="metricsGridRow1" borderColor="black">
        <mx:GridItem rowSpan="3" styleName="gridItem" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" >
            <mx:Label text="ABC" height="50" styleName="boldFontWeight"></mx:Label>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem rowSpan="3" styleName="gridItem" verticalAlign="bottom" horizontalAlign="center" >
            <mx:Label text="Total" height="50" styleName="boldFontWeight"></mx:Label>
        </mx:GridItem>
        <mx:GridItem rowSpan="3" styleName="gridItem" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" >
            <mx:Label text="XYZ" styleName="boldFontWeight"></mx:Label>
        </mx:GridItem>
    </mx:GridRow>
</mx:Grid>
```

If you need any other information then please let me know.
Your help is highly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you started.  Call `createGrid()` from a `createChildren()` override or an `initialize` event listener.

Note that the variables declared here will probably need to be class variables to make them easily accessible.

```
private function createGrid() {
    var metricsGrid:Grid = new Grid();
    //set other properties on metricsGrid

    var cashMetricsGridHeaderRow:GridRow = new GridRow();
    //set other properties on metricsGrid

    var item:GridItem = new GridItem();
    //set other properties on GridItem

    var label:Label = new Label();
    label.text = getTodaysDateWithTitle();

    item.addElement(label);
    cashMetricsGridHeaderRow.addElement(item);
    metricsGrid.addElement(cashMetricsGridHeaderRow);

    this.addElement(grid);
}
```